# One click to my community Leaderboard

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash, winterbash-leaderboard

Yes, I do check [my community](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com) leaderboard frequently, hard for me to go every time over there.

Is there any chance to get direct link in snowflake menu?